# percent field in rating_option_vote

Tags: ratings

I am trying to understand the fields present in `rating_option_vote` table.
Every `review` has one `rating_option_vote` associated with it.

As per my understanding, `rating_option_vote` contains the `value` of the rating given for the review along with other fields of course.

But, what's the use of `percent` field in `rating_option_vote` table?